# Cargar imagen al hacer clic en boton

Tags: java

Mi duda es la siguiente: como hago para cargar la imagen, desde un package llamadado imágenes, necesito hacerlo de esta forma:

> Al hacer clic en el botón 2, cargue la imagen en el botón 1.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no esta funcionando... Me pueden ayudar por favor.

```
btnFicha1 = new JButton(newImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/Imagenes/marcar.png")));
```

Answer (score 2):

revisando tu código se pueden ver varios errores.

1. Cuando utilizas  `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/Imagenes/marcar.png"))` debes omitir en la url la carpeta de `src` `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Imagenes/marcar.png"))` ya que el método `getResource` coloca como punto de partida la carpeta `src`.
2. El principal problema para realizar lo que indicas es por que esta creando una nueva instancia del botón (`new JButton`) esta nueva instancia debe ser agregada al `form` para ser mostrada, pero el proceso correcto es que utilices la variable `btnFicha1` para agregar el icono, te dejo un ejemplo del método:

   ```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Imagenes/marcar.png"));
           btnFicha1.setIcon(icon);
    }
   ```

Con esto te deberia de incionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona

Comment: Recuerda que la mejor manera de agradecer es marcar la respuesta como aceptada, @Keylor!